# Preposition choice: impression "of"/"about"/"from"

Tags: prepositions

Please advise me on what preposition I should use to be sure that I don't make a grammar mistake. This is a question in a company's questionnaire, where the customer is asked his opinion about the company.

The sentence is required to be concise and goes like this: "Impression of ABC Co."

Is *of* correct usage here? Or possibly *from* or *about*? And is there any general rule about this?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [definition of *impression*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impression), you'll see that the meaning in this context is a synonym for "the effect", and most definitions recommend the *of* usage.

It doesn't really make sense to say "the impression about" and whilst you can get an impression from some experience, it depends on the wider context of the sentence.

Given the information provided, I'd suggest you use "the impression of".

Answer (score 2):

No general rule. It depends on the sentence or phrase. ***Of*** works in this case. ***About*** would also probably work, but the first is shorter. ***From*** doesn't work for me in this context.